# Django Rest Framework - do not return url if imagefield doesnt exist

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have imagefield. The serializer is following

```
class CategoryWithImagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'name',
            'image_url',
        ]
```

In my model I have image described like this

```
image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Изображение', upload_to = 'images/', blank=True)
```

With this setup I get crash when there is an object without image.

I need a way of returning nothing instead of url if there is no image

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.url` raises an exception if `obj.image` is `None`.

You can update `get_image_url` as follows:

```
def get_image_url(self, obj):
    if obj.image:
        return obj.image.url
    else:
        return None
```